# PHP http_build_query special symbols

Tags: php, string, curl

I want to create an url out of an array with the help of http_build_query (PHP). This is the Array:

```
$a = array("skip" => 1, "limit" => 1, "startkey" => '["naturalProduct","Apple"]')
```

After calling

```
$s = http_build_query($a);
```

I get the following string $s:

```
skip=1&limit=1&startkey=%5B%22naturalProduct%22%2C%22Apple%22%5D
```

My problem is, that I would need an url like this:

```
skip=1&limit=1&startkey=["naturalProduct","Apple"]
```

which means, that I don't want to convert the following symbols: ",[]

I have written a conversion function which I call after the http_build_query:

```
str_replace(array("%5B", "%22", "%5D", "%2C"), array('[', '"', ']', ','), $uri);
```

My question now: Is there a better way to reach the expected results?

Comment: why yo need to do this? i think you need to encode to send data via GET or POST to decode in the other page. Otherwise you can do your own function to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question now: Is there a better way to reach the expected results?

Yes, there is something better. [`http_build_query`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/http_build_query) by default uses an URL encoding as outlined in RFC 1738. You just want to de-urlencode the string. For that there is a function that does this in your case: [`urldecode`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/urldecode):

```
$s = http_build_query($a);
echo urldecode($s);
```

I hope you are aware that your URL then is no longer a valid URL after you've done that. You already decoded it.

Comment: Thats the problem. I don't want to decode to full url, only the ",[] symbols. The url is used to call the REST api of couchdb and I don't know why, but if i use http_build_query without my str_replace afterwards, the query is rejected.

Comment: There must be some other error, I can't imagine that couchdb is neglecting standard procedures. However to answer what you're looking for, the function is called [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) you should prefer here over `str_replace`. Works with one array as replacement table like `array(find => replace, ...');`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to decode the special characters - they are automatically decoded when PHP's `$_GET` superglobal is generated. When I do `print_r($_GET)` with your generated string, I get this:

> Array ( [skip] => 1 [limit] => 1 [startkey] => [\"naturalProduct\",\"Apple\"] )

Which has decoded every character, but hasn't unescaped the double quotes. To unescape them, use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
echo stripslashes($_GET['startkey']);
```

This gives

> ["naturalProduct","Apple"]

Which you can then parse or use however you wish. A better solution, as ThiefMaster mentions in the comments, is to disabled `magic_quotes_gpc` in your `php.ini`; it's deprecated and scheduled for removal completely in PHP6.

Comment: If `stripslashes` is necessary the better solution would be disabling `magic_quotes_gpc` in php.ini. It's deprecated anyway and will be completely removed in PHP6.